# Can GWT be configured to output app logic in a .js file instead of .html?

Tags: gwt

I am aware of [why GWT emits app logic in a .cache.html file](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#What%27s_with_all_the_cache/nocache_stuff_and_weird_filenames).

But what if I knew my system would always be supplying .js files uncompressed?

Is there any way to make GWT output all the app logic in one .js file, or do I need to parse the .html file myself to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `xs` (deprecated, doesn't support DevMode) or `xsiframe` linkers:

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
```

For non-browser environments, you'll have to provide a custom linker. There's one for Node.js at https://github.com/cretz/gwt-node for instance.

Comment: Hmm, that sort of solves it, not entirely what I was looking for...   .cache.html files aren't any use for using GWT generated Javascript in an environment which doesn't use HTML/DOMs (e.g. Node).

Comment: OK, then you need another linker (i.e. make your own), specific to the environment you'll run the JS in. People have built linkers for WebWorkers, I guess it shouldn't be much different for Node.js (don't know if they've been open sourced).